# Custom ESlint parser to support a dynamic import() statement without `babel-eslint`

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, eslint

I need to support `import()` statement in webpack build process with ESlint checking.

In ESlint repo adviced to use https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint package.

But I don't want a Babel depency in the project to support one small feature.

I think it should be easer to write my own [eslint parser](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/working-with-plugins#working-with-custom-parsers). But I'm not shure that my approach is right.

This is my "parser":

```
var espree = require("espree");
// dumb-parser.js
exports.parseForESLint = function(code, options) {

  code = code.replace(/import\(/g, 'notAnImport(');


  code += `
    function notAnImport() { console.log('dumb') }
  `;

  return {
    ast: espree.parse(code, options),
    services: {
      foo: function() {
        console.log("foo");
      },
    },
    scopeManager: null,
    visitorKeys: null,
  };
};
```

As you see I simple replace `import(` part on some dumb stub.

Is there more elegant way to resolve that problem?

Comment: Since the dependency is only for local development anyway, why would using `babel-eslint` be any kind of problem?

Comment: We are using [Buble](https://buble.surge.sh/) that's doing most magic with Javascript compilation.

If we add `babel-eslint` then we will have two modules that doing mostly same things.

It looks not much DRY to me